# Auto encoder output dimension different from input dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am developing an auto encoder by using tensor flow. While calculating the loss function I encountered an error saying that the dimensions must be equal to find the mean. So I displayed the shape of input layer and output layer and both were different.I couldn't analyze where the problem is. The shapeof the image used in the dataset is (54,96,3)
Here is my code

```
##--------------------------------------------
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import os
import glob
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from functools import partial

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
images = []
for filename in os.listdir(folder):
    img = cv.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
    if img is not None:
        images.append(img)
return np.asarray(images)

def plot_image(image, cmap = "Greys_r"):
    plt.imshow(image.reshape([54, 96, 3]).astype(np.uint8), 
               cmap=cmap,interpolation="nearest")
    plt.axis("off")

def _parse_function(filename):
    image_string = tf.read_file(filename)
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_string, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image_decoded, tf.float32)
    return image

## Parameters
n_inputs = 96 * 54
BATCH_SIZE = 150
batch_size = tf.placeholder(tf.int64)

files = list(glob.glob(os.path.join('danceVideoFrame1','*.*')))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((files))

dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
dataset = dataset.batch(BATCH_SIZE)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
features = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    #print(sess.run(features).shape)
    #plot_image(sess.run(features), cmap = "Greys_r")
    #plt.show()

    ## Encoder
n_hidden_1 = 300
n_hidden_2 = 150  # codings

## Decoder
n_hidden_3 = n_hidden_1
n_outputs = n_inputs

learning_rate = 0.01
l2_reg = 0.0001

## Define the Xavier initialization
xav_init =  tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()
## Define the L2 regularizer
l2_regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(l2_reg)

## Create the dense layer
dense_layer = partial(tf.layers.dense,
                     activation=tf.nn.elu,
                     kernel_initializer=xav_init,
                     kernel_regularizer=l2_regularizer)
## Make the mat mul
hidden_1 = dense_layer(features, n_hidden_1)
hidden_2 = dense_layer(hidden_1, n_hidden_2)
hidden_3 = dense_layer(hidden_2, n_hidden_3)
outputs = dense_layer(hidden_3, n_outputs, activation=None)

print (outputs.shape)
print (features.shape)
#loss function
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - features))
## Optimize
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - features))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate)
train  = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

output:

```
$ python computery_dance.py
2019-01-11 03:11:14.446355: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
(?, ?, ?, 5184)
(?, ?, ?, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1628, in _create_c_op
    c_op = c_api.TF_FinishOperation(op_desc)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5184 and 3 for 'sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,?,?,5184], [?,?,?,3].

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "computery_dance.py", line 88, in <module>
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(outputs - features))
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 866, in binary_op_wrapper
    return func(x, y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_math_ops.py", line 8912, in sub
    "Sub", x=x, y=y, name=name)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1792, in __init__
    control_input_ops)
  File "C:\Users\J MANOJ\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1631, in _create_c_op
    raise ValueError(str(e))
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5184 and 3 for 'sub' (op: 'Sub') with input shapes: [?,?,?,5184], [?,?,?,3].
```

Comment: Next time, please format both your code & error trace accordingly (done it for you this time)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in shape is between the  `outputs` which has shape [?, ?, ?, 5184] and the `features` which has shape [?,?,?,3].  The problem is at `n_outputs = n_inputs`. The last dimension of the outputs should be equal to the number of channels of the inputs (which is 3 in your case) not to the multiplication of the two input dimensions (5184).